# Save PDF in landscape and with a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, landscape, export-to-pdf

With a lot of help I managed to fabricate a user form where I can choose which worksheet to export as PDF. After that it automatically makes a email with the created PDF's as attachments.

I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim xArrShetts As Variant
Dim xPDFNameAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
'xArrShetts = Array("test", "Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'Enter the sheet names you will send as pdf files enclosed with quotation marks and separate them with comma. Make sure there is no special characters such as \/:"*<>| in the file name.
xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me)

For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next


Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
    xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
'Check if file already exist
xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    
    xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & Sheets("Voorblad").Range("D24").Value & ".pdf"
    While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & xNum & ".pdf"
    xNum = 100
       
    Wend
    Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
        xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    End If
    xArrShetts(I) = xStr
Next

'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = "Administratie@holwerda.nl"
    .CC = "Jaap@holwerda.nl;Gerben@holwerda.nl;Peter@holwerda.nl"
    .Subject = Sheets("Voorblad").Range("B24").Value & "_" & Sheets("Voorblad").Range("D24").Value
    
    
    
    
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
    Next
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
End With
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
  Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
  For Each c In uF.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.Value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
        End If
  Next
  sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me

End Sub
```

I would like to export the PDF's in landscape style and in with a dynamic range.
now when I export the files sometimes it doesn't fit to one page.

Comment: Look into [Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.orientation), [PrintArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea) and [FitToPagesTall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.fittopagestall) property.

Comment: I am very new in coding, could you help me rewrite the code?

Comment: As @ 
Raymond Wu wants suggesting, you should properly format the Excel sheet **before exporting** it... Then, the function issuing the array should also check if any of the check box Caption to be used is (or not) a real sheet in the active workbook.

Comment: `xSht.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape`, `xSht.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1` before the line that exports the worksheet. If you need to change the PrintArea from what you have currently, provide the range similar to `xSht.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$C$5"`. This is pretty straightforward so far and I am out currently so if you are not going to attempt it, you have to wait for some kind soul to provide you the full solution. @ThomHaasert

Answer (score 1):

@faneDuru, @Raymond Wu
I tried your solutions and I think it works.

I have rewritten the code as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim xArrShetts As Variant
Dim xPDFNameAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
'xArrShetts = Array("test", "Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'Enter the sheet names you will send as pdf files enclosed with quotation marks and separate them with comma. Make sure there is no special characters such as \/:"*<>| in the file name.
xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me)

For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next


Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
    xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
'Check if file already exist
xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    
    xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & Sheets("Voorblad").Range("D24").Value & ".pdf"
    While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & xNum & ".pdf"
    xNum = 100
       
    Wend
    Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    xSht.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    xSht.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
    xSht.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$J$30"
        xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    End If
    xArrShetts(I) = xStr
Next

'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = "Administratie@holwerda.nl"
    .CC = "Jaap@holwerda.nl;Gerben@holwerda.nl;Peter@holwerda.nl"
    .Subject = Sheets("Voorblad").Range("B24").Value & "_" & Sheets("Voorblad").Range("D24").Value
    
    
    
    
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
    Next
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
End With
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
  Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
  For Each c In uF.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.Value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
        End If
  Next
  sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me

End Sub
```